# Download Rackspace MYSQL backup

Tags: mysql, rackspace

I've got historical backups for the last 2 years of my DB instance on Rackspace. I need to download a particular backup and pull some of the data on a specific day.

I don't see any documentation on this, or any actual way to do this. How would I go about this ?

Databases are stored in MYSQL format using Rackspace Cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to SSH in and do a `mysql dump` of your database or [find the location](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/recommended-cloud-backup-filedirectory-level-configuration-for-a-linux-server/) of your sql backups already on the server. Here are some [directions on how manually create a mysql dump.](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/exporting-data-from-mysql/)

After either locating your backup(s) on the server or creating a backup manually with `mysql dump`, you'll have to scp your `databaseName.sql` [file down to your local machine.](https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/25/t/325) The syntax is as follows for copying a file down to your machine:

```
scp YourUser@(CloudServer IP address):/path/to/file /path/to/location/
```